# How can I start a Fragment from within another Fragment that's part of a viewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewpager

I'm just getting into Android development in Kotlin, and I'm not quite sure what the correct approach to this situation is.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is have a `ViewPager` that scrolls through a list of items of the same type. The view associated with each item has a button. When I press the button, I would like to launch a new fragment, let's call it `iteminfo`. The `iteminfo` fragment should use the back stack so that you can hit the back button and return to the item view you were looking at before you hit the button.

The way I have it set up right now is this:

-My MainActivity add()s my ViewPager-containing fragment to the FragmentManager. (I am going for a one-activity architecture.)

-My ViewPager fragment contains a private inner class with a `PagerAdapter` that maintains a list of item fragments. The item fragments are generated and added to the PagerAdapter when the `ViewPager` fragment is created.

-The item fragments each have their own button. When the fragment is created, the button gets an `onClickListener`.

This is where I run into a bit of a dead end...

So far I've managed to get the iteminfo fragment to display and the item fragment to disappear, but my method was pretty janky: I performed a fragment transaction to add() the iteminfo fragment to the root element of my item_fragment.xml and then just set the visibility of the other elements in there to GONE. Cosmetically this gets me there, however if I hit the back button, the app just exits. So this is not going to cut it.

I have read that when switching between fragment views it is a good design to use a single empty FrameLayout in the .xml file as a fragment container and then add/remove fragments from that using the FragmentManager. This makes sense to me...

However, I am not sure how to remove() a fragment that is inside of a `ViewPager`. AFAIK you can't set a fragment's tag unless you're doing a fragment transaction. So if I want to perform replace(), I don't know how to reference the fragment I'm replacing.

Just as a Hail-Mary, I tried just replacing the whole `ViewPager` fragment (since this is added in MainActivity via a fragment transaction, I was able to tag it), but for some reason that just yields a NPE. It makes sense that a child fragment should not be able to replace its parent fragment, although I'm not 100% sure why it's a NPE.

Anyways, any enlightenment you can ship my way is greatly appreciated.

Edit: Added relevant code below.

MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val currentFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)

        if (currentFragment == null) {
            val fragment = ItemPagerFragment.newInstance()
            supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, "viewPager")
                .commit()
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

ItemPagerFragment.kt:

```
class ItemPagerFragment: Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager
    private lateinit var pagerAdapter: ItemPagerAdapter

    private val itemListViewModel:  ItemListViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ItemListViewModel::class.java)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_pager, container, false)

        viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.item_viewpager) as ViewPager
        pagerAdapter = ItemPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager())

        val items = itemListViewModel.items
        for (item in items){
            pagerAdapter.addFrag(ItemFragment.newInstance(item))
        }

        viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter

        return view
    }

    private inner class ItemPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager)
        : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm)
    {

        private val itemFragmentList: MutableList<ItemFragment> = ArrayList()

        override fun getItem(i: Int): Fragment {
            return itemFragmentList[i]
        }

        override fun getCount() = itemFragmentList.size

        fun addFrag(f: ItemFragment){
            itemFragmentList.add(f)
        }

    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): ItemPagerFragment {
            return ItemPagerFragment()
        }
    }

}
```

fragment_item_pager.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

ItemFragment.kt:

```
class ItemFragment(i: Item): Fragment() {

    private var item: Item = i;
    private lateinit var infoButton: Button

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, container, false)

        infoButton = view.findViewById(R.id.info_button) as Button

        infoButton.setOnClickListener{
            val fragment: InfoFragment =  InfoFragment.newInstance(item)
            val fragmentManager: FragmentManager = childFragmentManager
            val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()

            // this is where I have been having no success
            // and know my approach is certainly wrong/confused
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.item_frame, fragment)
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)
            fragmentTransaction.commit()
        }

        return view
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(i: Item): ItemFragment {
            return ItemFragment(i)
        }
    }

}
```

fragment_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_frame"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/info_button"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/some_string"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

InfoFragment.kt and fragment_info.xml could be anything, it doesn't matter what they are for the purposes of my question.

Comment: include the code what you have done then anyone can provide the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, the solution here is quite simple.

You have an Activity in which there is a FrameLayout, which is a container for fragments. Actually in it you put your fragment with ViewPager. When you click on the button, you simply put your new fragment on top of the fragment with ViewPager.

The bottom line is that all actions must occur through Activity. Those. you must have an interface that your Activity will implement, and the fragments will receive its instance from the context (for example, in the fragment's onAttach () method). When you click on your button, you simply pass your event to the Activity. And Activity is already creating a new fragment, thereby preserving the backstack.

It is important to understand that when working with fragments, they should not know anything about each other's existence. All operations must occur through abstraction and be performed by your parentView (Activity, ParentFragmen, etc.)